# Is new activity run in new thread?

Tags: android

When I create a new activity, is the new activity run in a new thread?

```
Log.d("testing", "before activity start");

intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class); //I put "Log.d("testing","in secondActivity")" in SecondActivity.onCreate()
startActivity(intent);

Log.d("testing", "after activity start");
```

I thought the sequence of the execution will be 
"before activity start" -> "in secondActivity" -> "after activity start"

But in fact, it is not. Anyone know the reason? So, is the new activity run in a new thread?

Answer (score 2):

NO it's not run in a new thread.  It's being run in the UI thread.  "By default, all of the application code in a single process runs in the main UI thread. This is the same thread that also handles UI events. The only exception is the code that handles IPC calls coming in from other processes. The system maintains a separate pool of transaction threads in each process to dispatch all incoming IPC calls. The developer should create separate threads for any long-running code, to avoid blocking the main UI thread." http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html

Comment: Since they are in the same thread, the sequence of the message display should be "before activity start" -> "in secondActivity" -> "after activity start" right? But it is not. The program should create the new activity first before it goes to the last line (the last line i mean is the "after activity start"), am I right?

Comment: No, because scheduling is non-preemptive. The way the UI framework is designed, no other activity (including the newly-started one) can actually run until the current method that was entered for the current activity terminates.

Answer (score 0):

It's run in the same thread (as are all the activities in your app), but creating the activity isn't done inside the `startActivity` call. Behind the scenes, the framework has a loop for all your activities, with a *message queue* of pending operations. The message queue receives messages about user input and state changes, and each time around the loop, it handles the next input from the queue, possibly calling one of the `Activity` or `View` callbacks (such as `onTouchEvent`).

When you call `startActivity`, it enqueues that request on your main thread's message queue. After your function returns, the loop will later take that request from the queue, create the activity, and call `onCreate` and all the other lifecycle callbacks. That's why you don't see `onCreate` called until after your function returns.

Incidentally, that's why you also need to be careful that none of your callbacks take too long to execute, or blocks: only after they return can the thread's loop deal with other requests from the queue, such as user input.